# Signal messenger on the desktop

Tags: chat, whatsapp

I currently use Telegram (because it just works very nicely) and WhatsApp (because stubborn people insist on using it). Both can be used on the desktop via http://web.whatsapp.com and http://web.telegram.org. Telegram also has a native desktop client for Linux.

From the security standpoint, both seem inferior to Signal (formerly TextSecure). Is there any way to use Signal on the desktop as well? I guess that would break the end-to-end encryption but I would be willing to share the key between desktop and mobile.

Comment: Possibly via bluestacks?

Comment: @Jonno: That is remote control of an Android device?

Comment: Note that you can use multiple devices without sharing private keys. Each device has it's own key pair. Messages are sent to your main active device, and this device then forwards the messages to your other devices using their public encryption keys.

See https://signal.org/docs/specifications/sesame/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are now desktop applications for Windows, Max, and Linux.

https://signal.org/download/

Comment: I would not call this “native”. It is an Electron app, which is a copy of the Chromium engine with the application written in JavaScript. “Native” would be like C++ and Qt. — So I am not sure that this is an improvement, before I had just one instance of Chromium running, now I would have two.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's [in the making](https://whispersystems.org/blog/signal-desktop/) - I'm not sure if it's a closed or open beta, so I don't know if you'll get instant access. [Further information](http://support.whispersystems.org/hc/en-us/articles/215077857-What-is-Signal-Desktop-How-can-I-sign-up-) and [more](http://support.whispersystems.org/hc/en-us/articles/215075157-How-do-I-use-Signal-Desktop-What-are-the-features-).

As stated in my comment also, if this doesn't work, you may be able to use [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) to virtualize Android apps within Windows.